# Error: Kerio Control VPN Client service is not running

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, kerio

I've faced with the error: "Kerio Control VPN Client service is not running" blinking just after a second from connection is success. No any errored messages in logs.

macos 10.15.7, kerio control vpn client 9.3.5

Comment: macos Big Sure the same error...